# seating 9 boys and 5 girls with certain restrictions (all girls next to each other , no girl next to the other and no girl on the sides)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> how many ways can we seat $9$ boys and $5$ girls
>
> 1. in a row such that every girl is seated next to the other and no boys in between
> 2. how many ways we can seat the boys such that no girls are next to each other no girls on the sides of the row
> 3. how would the answers change if instead of boys we have $9$ similar black balls and instead of girls $5$ similar white balls

---

For the first one we have $5!$ ways for the girls and $9!$ for the boys , so $5! \cdot 9!$ **(why don't we have to multiply by $2$ here?)**

For the second one I got stuck at a certain point , I first seat the $5$ girls we have $5!$ ways for that and then we need to fill the $6$ gaps between them for that we can place $6!$ boys and choose $6$ of the $9$ seats for them so $9 \choose 6$ $\cdot 6!$ then we are left with $3$ boys that we can seat in anyway , I thought about multiplying by $3!$ **but the answer in the book says
that the $3$ boys left have $6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8$ seats left why is that?**

For the third part if we want to place $9$ similar black balls and $5$ similar white balls such that the first answer requests we have $10$ ways but I could figure how to do it "mathematically" it was just obvious how to do it since the numbers are small

and for the third part with the second requests the answer is $D(6,3)$ because if we place the white balls first we will have 6 gaps and for the three balls left we only have one way to place them since they are similar it does not matter

I was also wondering how would the answers change if it was in a circular table instead of a row?

Thanks for any tips and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

$\bcancel{**(1)** You **do** need to multiply by $2$ because the group of girls could either be to 
the left of all the boys or to the right.}$

**Correction**
I read the question to be all boys together whereas it only says no boys **in between**

Then the block of girls have $10$ spots where they can be placed,, and the answer is $10*5!9!$

$\boxed{G} B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}B\boxed{G}$

**(2)** Here it is *far better* to seat the $9$ boys first so there are $8$ spots available for the girls (as they can't be at the edges) thus $9!\binom85 5!$

**(3)** It is asking how the answer**S** would change. The hint is to eliminate permutations within each category.

Comment: Thank you but for the second one why 8 spots left? if we seat 9 boys don't we have 5 seats left?

Comment: Not $8$ spots left, $8$ spots *available*. $B 1 B 2 B 3 B 4 B 5 B 6 B 7 B 8 B$

Comment: The way I read the first question, the answer should be $10!5!$ since there are $10$ possible locations for the block of girls.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks, I had misrakenly taken the boys also to be in a block